# Need help to recover my HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

just now i made a big mistake. unfortunately i clean my HDD with cmd mode. it wiped my all dates. it's more important to me. help me to recover that pls.
exactly what i have done is. my system running with windows 10pro OS with full date 1TB HDD. recently i tryed windows 11pro OS in another HDD. 11 looks better so i decide to change for 11. i plug both HDD same time but windows can't open. both HDD have BOOT MANAGER FILL. 'i deleted C partition on 1TB HDD' & restart again. still have same problem i searched in this platform. some one already face this problem and have solutions. i followed those steps in cmd mode to clean the SYSTEM partition in Old HDD. after clean the system partition overall HDD gone for Unallocated space. i want get them back. so help me to get the data in safe way please guys

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you have a local recovery agency near you?  That might be the best approach for you. Tools like Recuva and Easus can recover data but can also change things on disk making further recovery difficult.

Comment: No, I'm in rural village. it hard to find in my city. help me to get back data with out damage please@john

Comment: Look through the answers provided above your question. See if there is someone near you to guide you. Deleting data like you did may not always be recoverable.

Comment: ok thanks for Your consent@MR.John